# Way to save a dictionary as a separate reference in python

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, variable-assignment

When building a set of statistics from a dictionary, I process the various entries (such as by user). THus, I can build the various statistics for each user. While doing this, I also build the statistics for a dummy user that I can call "total". After the dictionary is completely built, I create a .csv file and output the statistics using the writerow method.

Since python iterates of the dictionary keys in no particular order, I want to cause the total user to print last. If I attempt to save the generated statistics into a save variable and then output it at the proper time, the save variable gets reset because python variables work by reference rather than value. That is the code

```
mystats = {}
totalstats = {}
for user in mydict
  #perform calculations to generate mystats dictionary entries
  if user == 'Total':
    totalstats = mystats
  else:
    outfile.writerow(mystats)
outfile.writerow(totalstats)
```

However, the actual output of totalstats is whatever set of values had been put into mystats last.

Is there a decent way to show that totalstats is to keep the explicit values within mystats that I had at the time of the assignment or do I need to calculate all the statistics at the end or do

```
for stattype in mystats:
  totalstats[stattype] = mystats[stattype]
```

While this works, I would rather have something of the type "totalstats = mystats' rather than do a large loop over the complete set of statistics or calculate the entire set of statistics for Total at the end of processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/dict/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy
totalstats = deepcopy(mystats)
```

If the dict doesn't contain mutable values then you can simply use `dict.copy()`.

Comment: I doubt a deep copy is needed here; `mystats.copy()` would be a shallow copy and plenty enough for the purposes of flat data that fits in a CSV row.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this.